# Not able to use cursor theme universally

Tags: cursor

Using i3wm

Using arch wiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Cursor_themes#XDG_specification

```
$ ls .local/share/icons/
Bibata-Modern-Ice/
```

In `~/.icons/default/index.theme`

```
[icon theme]
Inherits=Bibata-Modern-Ice
```

In `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`

```
[Settings]
gtk-cursor-theme-name=Bibata-Modern-Ice
```

Also used `ln -s ~/.icons/default/cursors .local/share/icons/Bibata-Modern-Ice/cursors/`, but it still doesn't work. It only works in firefox. Doesn't work in other areas of desktop.
LXAppearance also doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "universally"? Across users?

Comment: In other areas of the desktop like the wallpaper, polybar, other applications, etc. Using i3wm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim your order when creating the symlink is wrong. I just had the same problem but fixed it with:

```
cd ~/.icons/default
ln -s /usr/share/icons/Bibata-Modern-Classic/cursors/ cursors
```